# Run SQL script inside Docker container with Makefile

Tags: mysql, sql, docker, makefile

I have a Makefile to start a Docker Container running MySql.
I want to run my setup.sql file to setup my database but I keep having "Not such file or directory".
Here is my Makefile:

```
CONTAINER = NETFLIX

#DOCKER CONTAINER RELATED
NAME = --name $(CONTAINER)
PASS = -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=secret mysql:5.7
CHARSET = --character-set-server=utf8mb4
COLLATION = --character-set-server=utf8mb4

create:
    docker run -d -p 33061:3306 $(NAME) $(PASS) $(CHARSET) $(COLLATION)

start:
    docker start $(CONTAINER)

stop:
    docker stop $(CONTAINER)

remove: stop 
    docker rm $(CONTAINER)

reset_hard: stop remove create start

reset: stop start

#DATABASE RELATED (build, create, populate DB)

define run_script
    docker cp $(1) $(CONTAINER):/tmp/
    docker exec -it $(CONTAINER) mysql -u root -psecret < /tmp/$(1)
    echo "$(cat $(1))"
endef

setup:
    $(call run_script,setup.sql)

create_tables:
    $(call run_script,create_tables.sql)
```

Commands giving me troubles are:

```
make setup
make create_tables
```

Both of them give me "No such File or Directory".
Even if I run them from outside the Makefile.

Comment: Running them outside the makefile would be:

docker cp file.sql <container>:/tmp/
docker exec -it <container> mysql -u root -psecret < /tmp/file.sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possibly the most straightforward way to do this is to create a directory on the host containing the two `.sql` files and bind-mount it into the Docker container when it starts.  If there isn't already a database in persistent storage, then the container will run them automatically when it creates the database.  See "Initializing a fresh instance" in the [mysql image documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/).

```sh
MYSQL_PORT := 33061
MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD := secret
PORTS := -p $(MYSQL_PORT):3306
VOLUMES := -v $(PWD)/scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
ENVS := -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD)
IMAGE := mysql:5.7
RUN_OPTS := $(PORTS) $(VOLUMES) $(ENVS)
ARGS := --character-set-server=utf8mb4

run:
        docker run -d $(RUN_OPTS) $(IMAGE) $(ARGS)
```

If you can't do that, then you can run an ordinary MySQL client on the host.  This avoids several issues around the container having its own filesystem, effectively needing to be root to run `docker` commands, and shell quoting issues.  (`docker exec` probably shouldn't be part of your core workflow.)

```sh
setup: setup.sql
        mysql -h localhost -P $(MYSQL_PORT) -w -u root -p $(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD) < $<
create_tables: create_tables.sql
        mysql -h localhost -P $(MYSQL_PORT) -w -u root -p $(MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD) < $<
```

If you must use `docker exec`, then remember that shell redirection happens *before* control gets handed over to Docker land: if you `docker exec ... < file` your local shell opens `file` on the host for reading and that becomes the standard input to the command `docker exec` runs.  In you're example your shell command is reading from `/tmp/setup.sql` on the host and that's producing the "file not found" error.